# How do I look up NIC handles for whois?

Tags: whois

Sometimes, I look up the whois for an IP address, and only see NIC handles listed.

How do I look up those handles directly using the command line whois client? I've tried `whois <NIC-HANDLE>` but that doesn't work. I see that there is a `-T` option, but for the life of me can't figure out what type I should put for a NIC handle.

Better yet, is there a way to have each NIC handle listed by whois automatically looked up as part of the original query?

Answer (score 1):

Try here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIC_handle

Short answer: Discontinued. (Internic/ARIN)
RIPE may still support it. Though, I do not see 'nic-hdl' as a current search modifier on the official web site.